# Write a script to do content filtering with postfix

Tags: python, ruby, postfix-mta

How can i write in python or ruby a script to do content filtering in postfix via smtp or uucp (not pipe)? There is some examples?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need the whole mail body to process it, you could simply write a policy server for Postfix, see [Access policy delegation](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html).

If you need to process the whole mail, you have several possibilities, see [Postfix Content Inspection](http://www.postfix.org/CONTENT_INSPECTION_README.html).

You could either implement a [content filter](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#content_filter) (see [FILTER_README](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html)) which gets the mail via SMTP or LMTP and, after processing it, sends it back to Postfix through SMTP, or you could implement a milter, for which [appropriate libraries for Python](http://www.bmsi.com/python/milter.html) exist.

Comment: Check the examples that come with the Python milter library (e. g. ppymilter).